# impossible to get the height of an image in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, height, alert

I have 40 images with the class .myImage
with the css:

```
.myImage{
    position:absolute;
}
```

in jQuery I'm doing:

```
$('.myImage').each(function(){
    alert($(this).height());
});
```

I have the good height for something like the first 15 images, but then the alert is 0 until the very last image.
And I'm quite sure that every image are displayed because with an other jQuery script I'm giving to each of them a position and they are all displayed.

How come after 15 images the alert is 0?

Comment: If the image isn't loaded yet, how do you expect jquery (or the javascript engine) to obtain the height?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wait for all the images to load. The DOM will be ready, but the images won't have loaded. Use the `window.load` event instead of jQuery's `document.ready`

```
window.load = function(){
 $('.myImage').each(function(){
  alert($(this).height());
 });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Or wait only for specific images to load

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var images = $('.myImage');

  images.one('load', function (){
    images.each(function(){
      alert($(this).height());
    })
  }).each(function() {
      if(this.complete) $(this).load();
    });
});
```

Comment: Note however this won't work consistently after the first page load due to cross-browser differences in how the load event is triggered on cached images. (not to mention the handler will trigger when each one loads, not when they are all loaded.)